# Printing strings one letter at a time and adding onto them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python 3 and programming in general. I am not sure how to word my question so I'll just give an example.

So the user inputs a string such as `"home"`. The program should output:

```
h
ho
hom
home
```

This is what I have so far (I was just trying to get the numbering to work, but I thought I would add it just in case):

```
loopUpdate = 2

for i in range(1, len(mystery_string) + 1):
    for x in range(1, loopUpdate):
        print(x, end="")  
        loopUpdate += 1
    print()
```

Comment: the h ho hom and home should be on different lines.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What is your reasoning here with regards to the loopUdate? This can be done with a single loop over `range(1, len(mystery_string) + 1)`

Comment: my reasoning is that i  want the second loop to run different amounts of times

Answer (score 0):

This is unnecessarily complicated. You don't have to have two loops to print out characters at each index in a loop. You should use string slicing instead:

```
>>> "home"[0:2]
'ho'
>>> "home"[0:3]
'hom'
```

A function that does this would look something like this:

```
def print_loop(word):
    for i in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        print(word[0:i])
```

Output:

```
>>> print_loop("word")
w
wo
wor
word
```